# Line Chart Pointer color Change

Tags: activex, teechart

I am using the pointer '+' in my code. In the legend it is displayed in black color.I want that to be displayed as legend color.

If I change the property from editting=>series=>pointer=>default- TRUE it works fine for me.
Can you let me know how this can be achieved through code.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about your which is your exact question. If I understood correctly you should change pointer's pen color:

```
TChart1.Series(0).asLine.Pointer.Pen.Color = TChart1.Series(0).Color
```

A complete VB6 example:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False

    TChart1.AddSeries scLine
    TChart1.Series(0).FillSampleValues 10
    TChart1.Series(0).asLine.Pointer.Visible = True
    TChart1.Series(0).asLine.Pointer.Style = psCross
    TChart1.Series(0).asLine.Pointer.Pen.Color = TChart1.Series(0).Color
End Sub
```

If this doesn't help please provide more detailed information about your requirements.